# Combine 2 bytes into a short int in C

Tags: c, network-programming, int, hex, bit-shift

I am receiving a short int via network packet, which means it would come as 2 bytes in network byte order (big endian).

I would like to combine the two bytes I received into a short int variable on my machine, which is little endian byte order.

Example:

```
short int test = 400; //0x190 in big endian, 0x9001 in little endian
char testResponse[2] = {0x01, 0x90};
//here is my attempt
short int result = testResponse[1] << 8 | testResponse[0];
printf("%d\n", result); //-28671 when expecting 400
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The way to combine the two numbers would appear to be a 8 bit left shift than an OR, but this does not appear to give the correct result, and so I am wondering if anyone knows how my bit arithmetic is wrong.

Comment: There is no "8 bit left shift" in C. If there was, a shift count of `8` would invoke undefined behaviour. You are most likely subject to integer promotions, learn about them! And use unsigned types with fixed width. `char` is not guaranteed to be unsigned, nor is it guaranteed to have 8 bits. According to your comment at the now deleted answer: we need all relevant information. Or you get the code correct as I said.

Comment: The endian is how bytes are stored in memory, not how to compute values. To get `0x0190` you need `0x01 << 8 + 0x90`.

Comment: @JeremyRobertson Do you get the expected answer with `short int result = testResponse[0] << 8 | testResponse[1];
printf("%d\n", result);`  (indexes swapped)?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

int16_t result;
memcpy(&result, testResponse, sizeof(int16_t));
result = (int16_t)ntohs((uint16_t)result);
```

Some platforms, such as 32-bit arm, don't allow unaligned accesses. So use memcpy to get it into a correctly sized int before calling ntoh.

Comment: Pedantically: `*(uint16_t *)testResponse` is UB as `char testResponse[]` may not meet the alignment requirement of `uint16_t`.

Comment: It isn't even *pedantic* but practical on many ARM processors. Also, strict-aliasing, compilers might misbehave even on platforms where unaligned access might work.

Comment: @chux is correct. I've added a memcpy to work around the alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the indices. The number is 0x0190 in little endian, but your code calculates the big-endian number, which is `0x9001`, which, in signed short will also cause integer overflow upon left-shift to the sign bit.

The code indeed isn't very portable as `char` might be signed or unsigned. While it might be true that majority of architectures have unsigned chars, the truth is that majority of C programs are written for signed char architecture - the x86. There the fact that 0x90 is sign-extended might cause wild unexpected results.

Thus more portable would be

```
char testResponse[2] = {0x01, 0x90};
unsigned int tmp = (unsigned)testResponse[0] << 8 | (unsigned)testResponse[1];
short result = tmp;  // implementation-defined behaviour
printf("%d\n", result); // 400
```